# New Dropdown Appear When Previous Dropdown is Selected

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make a dropdown appear **only** when specific data are selected from the previous dropdown. If it is not selected, then it won't show up.

I include a picture to describe more of this Dynamic Dropdown
and as you can see, I will select Flavor either from Sweet or Sour.

[image]

So, if I choose Flavor: **Sweet**. 
It will display another dropdown of Size and Quantity.

But, if I choose Flavor: **Sour**. 
It will only display a dropdown of Size and hide the Quantity dropdown.

I've tried to search online but to no avail. I only found this [AngularJS](http://plnkr.co/edit/b7iODzCUjfe9Mp5dCzMt?p=preview) but they only disable the selection of the dropdown. I have no experience with AngularJS. Is there any way to do the dropdown using HTML or CSS or JavaScript?

What is the right way to resolve this? Any suggestion? Thank you in advance :)

AngularJS:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>
      document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />')
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script
      data-require="angular.js@1.2.x"
      src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js"
      data-semver="1.2.25"
    ></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

    <label
      ><h4><b>Transaction Type</b></h4></label
    >
    <select
      id="transtype"
      style="margin: auto; width: 100%;"
      ng-model="data.transtype"
      ng-options="type.name for type in listOne"
      ng-disabled="isDisabled"
      ng-change="hideFields()"
    >
      <option value="" selected="selected">--Select Transaction Type--</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />

    <label
      ><h4><b>Select Bank</b></h4></label
    >
    <select
      id="beneBank"
      style="margin: auto; width: 100%;"
      ng-model="data.beneBank"
      ng-options="type.name for type in listTwo"
      ng-disabled="disableFields"
    >
      <option value="" selected="selected">--Select Bank--</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling new appeared dropdown when previous dropdown selected. I've figured out the code using **html** and **javascript** after a long research and it worked perfectly on me.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#size').hide();

     $('#flavor').change(function () {
        if ($('#flavor option:selected').text() == "Sweet"){
            $('#size').show();
        }
         else { 
              $('#size').hide();
         }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='flavor' name = 'flavor'>  
    <option>------------</option>
    <option value='SW'>Sweet</option>
    <option value='SO'>Sour</option>
    
</select>

<select name='size' id='size'>
    <option>------------</option>
    <option>Small</option>";
    <option>Big</option>";
    
</select>
```